# AWS Lambda handler for Quarkus native application

Tags: java, kotlin, aws-lambda, quarkus

I have been playing around with Quarkus and the custom (native) runtime for AWS lambda but I'm facing a quite simple (I believe) problem that I don't manage to get a solution in any documentation (both AWS nor Quarkus).

I'm not able to get a list of JSON objects to de-serialize in my code. When I test my lambda function from the console with my JSON payload I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassCastException",
  "errorMessage": "java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.example.InputObject"
}
```

My JSON payload is:

```
[
  {
    "description": "test description",
    "name": "A name"
  }
]
```

My handler in Kotlin:

```
class LambdaHandler : RequestHandler<List<InputObject>, OutputObject> {

    override fun handleRequest(input: List<InputObject>, context: Context?): OutputObject {
        val names: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
        input.mapTo(names) { it.name }
        // do stuff with names
        return OutputObject("", context?.awsRequestId)
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm curious, what made you use `List<InputObject>`?

Comment: HI @geoand it's to use the generic interface for the `List` also suggested in the AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html#java-handler-types

Comment: Understood thanks. This sounds like a bug, so can you please open an issue?